# Understanding RHost, LHost, PORT

Tags: ip, metasploit, kali-linux

I'm a complete beginner who wants to learn pen testing. I'm having trouble of understanding this 3 specific **IP's** the **remote host**, **local host**, and **PORTS**.

In my own understanding the **remote host** is the **target's** IP address and the **local host** is your IP address but if your target is outside of your network you will use your public IP address and if your target is inside in your network you will use the local IP right?

But I don't understand what **PORTS** are.

In many YouTube tutorial they are just inputting **"6666"**, **"4444"**. Can someone explain me what is the use and where can i find what my **PORT** is?

Comment: This is more of a basic networking question - the port is a way to indicate which service running on a server should respond to a given request, a bit like how a block of apartments can have multiple recipients. The building address would be roughly equivalent to an IP address, and the exact apartment vaguely like a port. You'll need to learn some more about networking to be able to pen test effectively though.

Comment: Am i jumping/skipping too much sir @Matthew?

Comment: Probably, yes - you might be better off reading up on how TCP/IP works, and once you understand that thoroughly, look at connecting to authorised systems with tools like `nc`

Comment: This question isn’t in scope for this stack exchange.  Regardless, before you try and learn pen testing I suggest you first learn some basic networking concepts. I suggest you start with learning what an IPv4 address is, what the TCP protocol is and how they can work together.

Comment: @TheJulyPlot do you have any suggestions or websites that i can learn networking? Thankssss

Comment: @nethkennnnn have a look here: https://www.cybrary.it/course/comptia-network-plus/

Comment: @TheJulyPlot Oh thanks my friend recommends it too. Thankss! :) Better i should study the basic of linux and social engineering too right?